# Ingredients in Pfizer vaccine

Tags: coronavirus, medicine, vaccination, vaccine

The ingredients in the Pfizer vaccine have been listed in a number of websites, including government healthcare ones. [This site](https://blackdoctor.org/these-are-all-the-ingredients-of-pfizers-covid-vaccine/) claims that the list includes ALL of the ingredients of the vaccine. Considering that things like sodium chloride have been included on the list, that would seem to suggest that it is indeed comprehensive. The ingredients list is the following:

- mRNA
- Lipids (including ((4-hydroxybutyl)azanediyl)bis(hexane-6,1-diyl)bis(2-hexyldecanoate), 2 [(polyethylene glycol)-2000]-N,N-ditetradecylacetamide, 1,2-Distearoyl-sn-glycero-3- phosphocholine, and cholesterol)
- Potassium chloride
- Monobasic potassium phosphate
- Sodium chloride
- Dibasic sodium phosphate dehydrate
- Sucrose

I cannot help but feel suspicious about whether this truly is the full list. For a synthetic medicine, I would expect a much longer list with stabalisers, peservatives, adjuvants etc.

So my questions are: Is it reasonable to assume that this truly is the entire contents of the vaccine, sans water? And, where are the adjuvants? There is no aluminium here.

EDIT: I feel like I have been downvoted because my post gives the impression that I am an anti vaxer. I emphasise I am not. I just really wish to know what is inside these vaccines and how they work, and why the things that I expect to be inside are not. Because vaccine are such a sensitive topic now, it makes sense for anyone posting iformation about them to be very careful about what they include. This extends to publishing incomplete ingredients lists, which are not *explicitly said* to be complete (so there is no legal repurcusiion) although the wording makes it seem like such. I have no issue with some aluminium being present in vaccines. People consume aluminium all the time when drinking soda pops from cans. But, I do want to be fully aware of everything that is inside of them and how they work, and I think it is reasonable to when you are putting something inside of yourself. As someone with a family history of severe autoimmune conditions, I am also concerned about the presence of other adjuvants and I think justifiably so. Again, this is just to say that I am not an anti-vaxxer at all, but I am all for knowing what is inside a vaccine and how they work. And unfortuantely the scare around vaccines means that it can be hard to get complete information about them, because people with little scientific background may be scared by what they see in a complete list as they don't understand it. Thus it is discretely censored, and I understand why.

Comment: An adjuvant increases the immune response to some antigen. No one wants any immune response to any component of these vaccines; including an adjuvant would be silly. I don't see how this question can be answered with any *biology*, though - you're basically just expressing skepticism about a manufacturer's ingredient list. They'd get in quite a bit of trouble with regulators if it's incomplete.

Comment: @BryanKrause I assume you downvoted, which I think is unjustified. I am not skeptical about the *manufacturer's* ingredients list. I have not seen this published by Pfizer themselves. Rather, by other websites. The reputable ones have not claimed that this is the entire list and could merely be listing the things that they believe are important and/or would not scare the public. Only a non-reputable one has claimed that this is the entire list.

Comment: Secondly, I think it is perfectly valid to question why there are not more preservatives/stabilisers (the lipids are some stabilisers, and I think the sucrose acts as a preservative or stabiliser here too). AND, why there are no adjuvants I recognise. As is mentioned in the website below, "many vaccines contain aluminium salts... they act as adjuvants" https://vk.ovg.ox.ac.uk/vk/vaccine-ingredients#Added%20ingredients

Comment: The point is that one *wants* to amplify the immune response such that there is one towards a small amount of viral material. Now I do not know whether the white blood cells directly detect the viral mrna and create some protein/rna 'antibody' against this, or whether the mrna gets into cells and is expressed as an antigen which the white blood cells make antibodies for. I presume it is the latter, since the mrna encodes the viral protein spike specifically. In any case, since little material is injected, amplifying the immune response would be beneficial.

Comment: @Meep, I've answered your question. Though it seems like a better question to ask (and the crux of your inquiries) is "Why do mRNA vaccines not require adjuvants, but other vaccine types (like inactivated influenza vaccines) often do?"

Comment: @acvill Thank you for the suggestion. It seems like this may be a better way to go, as I think I am getting downvoted as people think I am just another anti vaxer looking for reasons to scaremong people. Not the case at all!

Comment: @Meep You do not want an immune response to the lipids or mRNA or any ingredient in the injection. You ideally want the mRNA to enter cells without the immune system knowing anything about it, you only want an immune response to the spike protein that can be used to identify active virus particles. You may not be an anti-vax person but you are really carrying a lot of their baggage.

Comment: @BryanKrause Ok thank you for telling me that the immune response is meant to be towards the expressed antigens and *not* the mrna (I would never have thought of the lipids triggering immune response). This may be why the mrna vaccines do not require adjuvants, just a longer amount of time to create enough antigens from the mrna templates to have a sufficiently large immune response.

Comment: @BryanKrause Also, yes it may be the case that I carry anti-vax baggage. I come from a family of scientist turned anti-vaxers. However I am trying to educate myself. My questions are ones of genuinely trying to understand vaccines, and formulate my own opinion as to whether they may be harmful *in certain circumstances* or no (obviously mass use of vaccines rules out severe harmful effects in the general population). Being attacked like this makes me scared to ask whether it is harmful to the cells which the mrna enters and which express the antigens. From my knowledge of the immune response

Comment: these would be detroyed by the white blood cells. I think it is a valid question to ask. I know it is no issue to lose a few cells, but if the mrna gets into many cells, or the immune response goes awry because some cells are expressing thsi antigen, then it can be harmful.

Comment: I don't see the point of posting a likely disreputable site and essentially asking "is this right", when one can just access the official materials descriptions from the FDA, the manufacturer, and so forth.  You also baselessly claim "Thus it is discretely censored, and I understand why"  Those are the reasons for my downvote.

Comment: @Meep Being destroyed by the immune system is the fate of every infected cell that is recognized as such cell. So you lose a few cells because of the vaccination, however these are easily replaced. The same process (but on a ways bigger scale) happens throughout your whole body (and not only around the injection site) when you are infected with SARS-CoV-2.

Comment: @Meep Generally, there is no need for an immune response against mRNA. Free ssRNA is very unstable in cells because of RNAi. There are plenty RNA-dependent RNA polymerases floating in cells that detect (both endogeneous and exogeneous) free ssRNAs, such as mRNAs. These synthesise the complement, and the dsRNA is then rapidly degraded because dsRNA is never functional in human cells. In fact, this system probably evolved as a defense mechanism against infections from ss/dsRNA viruses.

Comment: @Meep And, if anything, the production and publication process around vaccines effective (or non-effective) against SARS-CoV-2 shows that there is no discrete, indiscrete or whatsoever censorship. The fact that potential side effects are widely publicly discussed that even occur less often in the vaccinated population than in the non-vaccinated population suggests that there could not be more transparency. In fact, I consider the development and publication of these vaccines to be examplary for a very transparent process (at least on the side of scientists).

Comment: @Meep For your interest in scientific evidence on the subject of vaccinations, I suggest you have a look at this excellent blog: https://www.skepticalraptor.com

Answer (score 3):

The source for the linked  article is [this FDA factsheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20210630223745/https://www.fda.gov/media/144413/download), which gives the following description for the Pfizer-BioNTech COVID-19 Vaccine (emphasis mine):

> The Pfizer-BioNTech COVID-19 Vaccine is supplied as a frozen suspension in multiple dose vials; each vial must be diluted with 1.8 mL of sterile 0.9% Sodium Chloride Injection, USP prior to use to form the vaccine. Each dose of the Pfizer-BioNTech COVID-19 Vaccine contains 30 mcg of a nucleoside-modified **messenger RNA** (modRNA) encoding the viral spike (S) glycoprotein of SARS-CoV-2.
>
> Each dose of the Pfizer-BioNTech COVID-19 Vaccine also includes the following ingredients: **lipids** (0.43 mg (4-hydroxybutyl)azanediyl)bis(hexane-6,1-diyl)bis(2-hexyldecanoate), 0.05 mg 2[(polyethylene glycol)-2000]-N,N-ditetradecylacetamide, 0.09 mg 1,2-distearoyl-sn-glycero-3-phosphocholine, and 0.2 mg cholesterol), 0.01 mg **potassium chloride**, 0.01 mg **monobasic potassium phosphate**, 0.36 mg **sodium chloride**, 0.07 mg **dibasic sodium phosphate dihydrate**, and 6 mg **sucrose**. The diluent (0.9% Sodium Chloride Injection, USP) contributes an additional 2.16 mg sodium chloride per dose.
>
> **The Pfizer-BioNTech COVID-19 Vaccine does not contain preservative**. The vial stoppers are not made with natural rubber latex.

The factsheet does not mention adjuvants.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. The wording is quite waffly though. They do not claim to list all of the ingredients, just other stuff that the vaccine contains. Considering the concern over aluminium in vaccines, they might have reason not to mention it, but have themselves covered by not claiming it isn't there.

Comment: You expect a statement like "This is a comprehensive list of ingredients."? No one does that. The wording is succinct, not waffly. The FDA has no reason to exclude ingredients from their fact sheets (*e.g.* note the mercury content of Fluzone is [clearly stated](https://www.fda.gov/media/119856/download)).

Comment: I am not. At all. But I do expect more explicit wording. Thank you in any case.

Comment: I've edited my comment, sorry for the presumption of anti-vax sentiment. We get a lot of that here. Additionally, the [hep A vaccine factsheet](https://www.fda.gov/files/vaccines%2C%20blood%20%26%20biologics/published/Package-Insert---HAVRIX.pdf) clearly states its aluminum content.

Comment: Note that the temperature handling requirements act as a preservative, as likely does the sucrose content of the vaccine (dilution occurs only just before administration).  The reason for the lack of adjuvants is covered in the comments under the question.